# How to plot scatter plot using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, k-means, scatter-plot

I have used this code to create clusters and I want to plot the scatter plot of the clusters. The vectorAssembles_01 produces data with ID and features. Both should be used to plot the scatter plot.When I am running the code in google Collab I am getting an error message stating RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison. please correct if I am wrong.

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FEATURES_COL = ['Height(CM)', 'Weight(KG)', 
                      'Crossing', 'Finishing', 'HeadingAccuracy', 
                      'ShortPassing', 'Volleys', 'Dribbling', 'Curve',
                      'FKAccuracy', 'LongPassing', 'BallControl', 
                      'Acceleration', 'SprintSpeed', 'Agility', 
                      'Reactions', 'Balance', 'ShotPower', 'Jumping', 
                      'Stamina', 'Strength', 'LongShots', 'Aggression', 
                      'Interceptions', 'Positioning', 'Vision', 'Penalties', 
                      'Composure', 'Marking', 'StandingTackle', 'SlidingTackle']

vecAssembler_01 = VectorAssembler(inputCols=FEATURES_COL, outputCol="features")
df_kmeansn = vecAssembler_01.transform(df).select('ID','features')
df_kmeansn.show()
#df_kmeansn.plot("ID","fearures",kind="Scatter")
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
x = df_kmeansn.ID
y = df_kmeansn.features
ax.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.8, edgecolors='none')
```

The output of the df_kmeansn is as shown below.

[image: output of the df_kmeansn]

Comment: `scatter` only takes `x` and `y` as 1D arrays of numbers. Your `y` is a 1D array of arrays.

Comment: Yes, in my case y is a 1d array of arrays. But may I how to plot only y in a scatter plot. Thank you

Comment: which line is raising the error?

Comment: @andhrabullodu if you want to plot 1D data you either want a histogram or bar chart, not a scatter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can just plot Spark Dataframe directly, perhaps you should call `to_pandas` first:

```py
# ...

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

df_pandas = df_kmeansn.to_pandas()

x = df_pandas.ID
y = df_pandas.features
ax.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.8, edgecolors='none')
```